# How to switch between screen dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in IOS development...i come from `android` background
I want to implement a login in xcode...
and when a user clicks on login button and if successful, for the `first login` it should go to OTP screen and after the user is a registered user...whenever he/she clicks on the login button it should go to home screen...
so basically i want the `login` button to switch to **different screens** (without navigation )

for example this func is when login is done

```
func LoginDone()
{
    if (registeredUser()){
     //switch to OTP screen and also send The username to that .swift file
    }

    else{
     //switch to homescreen and send some data to that .swift file
    }     
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: yes i am using storyboards for now...

Comment: you can use segue to go different screens and give each segue a identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect two segues from the login screen.

In the storyboard, connect a segue from the login screen to the OTP screen, and another segue from the login screen to the home screen. Remember to start dragging from the controllers in the storyboard, *not* any of the views in a controller.

Give each segue an identifier in the right panel. I will call the first segue (login -> OTP) "showOTP" and the second segue (login -> home screen) "showHome".

In the if statement:

```
func LoginDone() {

    if (registeredUser()){
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "showOTP", sender: data)
    } else {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHome", sender: data)
    }

}
```

Here I used `data` as the `sender` argument. Please replace this with the data that you want to send to the other view controller.

Then, override `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showOTP" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! OTPController // Here replace OTPController with the class name of the OTP screen
        vc.username = sender as! String // username is a property in OTPController used to accept the value passed to it. If you don't have this, declare it.
    } else if segue.identifier == "showHome" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! HomeController // Here replace HomeController with the class name of the home screen
        vc.data = sender as! SomeType // data is a property in HomeController used to accept the value passed to it. If you don't have this, declare it.
        // replace SomeType with the type of data you are passing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...very well explained